# How to deep-link directly to an app in Okta Mobile on iOS

Tags: ios, single-sign-on, deep-linking, okta

We can send a link to someone formatted as `okta://` and it will launch the Okta mobile app, but I would like to know if there is a way to deep link to a specific app in Okta mobile?
Something like `okta://appname`
or better yet would be `okta://appname/specificpageinapp`
I have tried all sorts of options, but none seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

The Okta Mobile app doesn't support deep linking as you described.

You *may* be able to deep-link directly into native iOS applications using a similar URL Scheme (`exampleapp://page/example`). If the native iOS app is integrated with Okta, this might work as you expect.

However, it sounds like what you might actually want to do is link directly into the embedded web view of a web application in Okta. If that is the case, I suggest reaching out to Okta support with a feature request and the use case that you're trying to solve, so that it can get the attention of the product manager for the Okta Mobile app.